Why is XAF Template creating projects with the wrong minor version number?
I like to create new XAF projects as a way of checking I am using the correct packages
Yet I am unable to do this after upgrading to a new minor version.
For example, I have installed the latest version of XAF 24.1.5
Yet when I create a new solution with the wizard I see in Solution Explorer that the package version is 24.1.3

When I look at the project the minor version does not display
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <CheckEolTargetFramework>false</CheckEolTargetFramework>
    <Deterministic>false</Deterministic>
    <AssemblyVersion>1.0.*</AssemblyVersion>
    <FileVersion>1.0.0.0</FileVersion>
    <Configurations>Debug;Release;EasyTest</Configurations>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="Model.DesignedDiffs.xafml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Model.DesignedDiffs.xafml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.ExpressApp" Version="24.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.ExpressApp.CodeAnalysis" Version="24.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.ExpressApp.ConditionalAppearance" Version="24.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.ExpressApp.EFCore" Version="24.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.ExpressApp.Objects" Version="24.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.ExpressApp.Validation" Version="24.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.Persistent.Base" Version="24.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.Persistent.BaseImpl.EFCore" Version="24.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="8.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory" Version="8.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies" Version="8.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" Version="5.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.11.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="6.34.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

I see no versions 24.1.3 in the GAC
Why are the templates creating projects with incorrect version numbers?
I have tried setting the package source to
C:\Program Files\DevExpress 24.1\Components\System\Components\Packages

Then right clicking the solution and choosing Restore Nuget Packages
Also I have tried setting the package source to my Dev Express Feed
Neither solve the problem.
Update
I have no Visual Studio folder in %USERPROFILE%\Documents 
I do have a Visual Studio 2022 folder.
With an empty C# folder in it.

In VS2022 Tools->Options-> Projects and Solutions->Locatons 
the User project template location is set to 
 C:\Users\kirst\Documents\Visual Studio 2022\Templates\ProjectTemplates


In the end I uninstalled DevExpress 24.1.5 and reinstalled it.
Repairing did not help.

The project templates are comes from Visual Studio installation, but the packages and releases are comes from NuGet. from a different source.
If your project template is not correct, then you can modify it with the following steps:

Locate the .zip file that contains the template. User project templates are located at %USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio \Templates\ProjectTemplates.
Extract the .zip file.
Modify or delete the current template files, or add new files to the template.
Open, modify, and save the .vstemplate XML file to handle updated behavior or new files.
Select the files in your template, and from the right-click or context menu, and choose Send to > Compressed (zipped) folder.
Put the new .zip file in the same directory as the old .zip file.
Delete the extracted template files and the old template .zip file.

For more information about the .vstemplate schema, see Visual Studio template schema reference (extensibility).
For more information about what you can parameterize in the source files, see Template parameters.
More info:

Customize templates
Create project and item templates


Thank you for the pointers. I updated my question.
